# Expand div Border to Height of Tallest Sibling and Expand Background Colour to Full div Height

Tags: css, html

I am currently redesigning a table using divs and CSS (because the table displays poorly on mobile devices).  However, I am stuck with part of the design.  I cannot seem to get the borders of my divs to extend their full height (which is determined by a sibling) and I cannot seem to get the background colour in my "header" column to span the full height of the div.

```
#sol-table {
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#sol-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.sol-state-statute, .sol-state-open, .sol-state-promissory, .sol-state-oral, .sol-state-written {
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.sol-state {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#sol-header, .sol-state {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sol-header, .sol-state-name {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.sol-state-odd {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.sol-state-even {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.sol-header-info, .sol-state-info {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.sol-state-info {
    text-align: center;
}

.sol-state-name, .sol-state-statute {
    text-align: left;
}

#sol-header-state, .sol-state-name {
    width: 12%;
}

#sol-header-open, .sol-state-open {
    width: 15%;
}

#sol-header-statute, .sol-state-statute {
    width: 40%;
}



<div id="sol-table">

    <div id="sol-table-content">

        <div id="sol-header">
            <div class="sol-header-info" id="sol-header-state">State</div>
            <div class="sol-header-info" id="sol-header-written">Written Contracts</div>
            <div class="sol-header-info" id="sol-header-oral">Oral Contracts</div>
            <div class="sol-header-info" id="sol-header-promissory">Promissory Notes</div>
            <div class="sol-header-info" id="sol-header-open">Open-Ended Accounts<br />(e.g., Credit Cards)</div>
            <div class="sol-header-info" id="sol-header-statute">Link to Statute(s)</div>
        </div>

        <div class="sol-state sol-state-odd" id="sol-alabama">
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-name">Alabama</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-written">#</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-oral">#</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-promissory">#</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-open">#</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-statute">Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="sol-state sol-state-even" id="sol-alaska">
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-name">Alaska</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-written">#</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-oral">#</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-promissory">3</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-open">#</div>
            <div class="sol-state-info sol-state-statute">Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />Line 4<br />Line 5<br />Line 6<br /></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/KYthh/.

As you can see, the "Alabama" and "Alaska" divs have a background colour which is not properly expanding to fill the div, and most of the rest of the divs in the table (with the tallest div being the clear exception) have borders which are not properly expanding to their full height.

I would prefer to find a way to accomplish these tweaks without resorting to display-table or similar, because I (unfortunately) have to get this code working in IE.  If possible, I would prefer to use CSS instead of jQuery.

Comment: What it the problem with tables on mobile devices in your case? Probably you can solve it the other way round use `table` and set the `display` to `block` for `table`, `tr`, ... for mobile devices or with conditional comments for everything else then the IE version that don't display correctly.

Comment: This seems like tabbular data so I don't know why you're not using a table? I know you said that the table doesn't play nice on mobile but you can get tables to be responsive. And what you're trying to accomplish would be much easier with `rowspan` `colspan` and the like. 

http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables
http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

Comment: I actually already have a <table> version of the data I'm attempting to format using only divs and CSS.  I'm well aware that going the table route may make sense, but the result simply does not render well on mobile devices.